# angular removes ng-model variable if ng-required is true

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation

as in the title.. how to prevent such operations to happen? Here is a [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) to the official site, see the example. The variable `user.name` is bound to the first input `userName` and if the input is empty the object `user.name` is removed. How can I disable this functionality of angularjs?

Comment: Sample code perhaps and a description of the problem?

Comment: the code is on the example in the link... I didn't post my code because its the same as in the example.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying. The question could have been a bit clearer. OK, so what do you want to set `user.name` to? After all, if the input `userName` is empty, then the model should be empty?

Comment: Of course, once you set it once, it will keep it.

Comment: Here is a basic fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yzg250uL/

Comment: I have a json form, its fields are binded to inputs and I load the json form to my database and I want to enssure that all objects are present. The default value object in that form is removed and I can't save it to my DB.

Comment: as in the fiddle is shown, if you put the `ng-required="true"` attribute to the input the object `params.user` dissapears and I don't want that. That object should be null or empty.

Comment: try this.. `<input ng-model="user.name" required ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}">`

Comment: So modify the fiddle to reflect your actual issue, @S3B4ST14N.

Comment: @S3B4ST14N, I posted my comment as an answer so that you can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"` to update the model even for invalid entries.

```
<input ng-model="user.name" required ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 option

1. remove `required` from input tag it allows you to send back empty string to your backend

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.params = {
    user: "John"
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input name="userName" ng-model="params.user" />
  <hr/>
  <pre>{{params| json}}</pre>
</div>
```

2. Option two validate your form before you send it to backend.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    name: "John"
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>



<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="someForm">
    <input name="userName" ng-model="user.name" required name="userName" />
    <span ng-show="someForm.userName.$error.required">User Name required</span>
    <br/>{{user | json}}
    <br/>

    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="someForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to send an Form with an empty input (an invalid input - as angular interprets it), later on an user will get that form and he will fill it. I used the solution which @Vinay K suggested, to use `ng-model-options` directive. Thanks for your help @Vinay K